# multiple-value reader.ReadString() in single-value context

Tags: go

Go newbie here.

I am trying to run very simple example on `go1.11.4 windows/amd64`

Here is my code below;
sandbox: https://play.golang.org/p/GoALi4HYx3L

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Print("Enter a grade: ")
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Enter text: ")
    input := reader.ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Println(input)
}
```

And I am getting following error:

> prog.go:13:28: multiple-value
>   reader.ReadString() in single-value context

Am I missing something here?

Comment: It has two return values, and you are assigning them to one variable `input` https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadString

Comment: If you're reading this because of the book "Head First Go," know this example is intended to give that error. You just have to read the paragraphs that follow this code snippet for their explanation on how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the documentation for ReadString, especially the part that describes return values (Tip: it is in the title of the section).

https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadString

Also, it worse check this reading also
https://gobyexample.com/multiple-return-values

Comment: Thanks, that example helped in a good way. Go documentation seems poor, in terms of giving usage examples, compared to Java and Python.